# azure storage-blob isInstrumentationSuppressed is not a function

Tags: javascript, browser, sdk, azure-blob-storage, open-telemetry

I try to run .download() on my BlobClient, and am met with the error:
`api.isInstrumentationSuppressed is not a function`

I have ensured I am using the appropriate method for the browser.

I am running the below code to get data from my blob storage.

```
async function readBlob(blobName) {
          const blobSvc = new ContainerClient(
            {{containerUrl}},
            new StorageSharedKeyCredential({{accountName}}, {{accountKey}})
           );
            const blobClient = blobSvc.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

// In browsers, get downloaded data by accessing downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody
            const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download();
//The rest of the function does not run bc above line throws ERROR
            const downloaded = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody);
            console.log("Downloaded blob content", downloaded);
            async function blobToString(blob) {
                const fileReader = new FileReader();
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    fileReader.onloadend = (ev) => {
                        resolve(ev.target.result);
                    };
                    fileReader.onerror = reject;
                    fileReader.readAsText(blob);
                });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    }
```

When I try to use .download() in my nodeApp it works with no issues, using the [Node Version of the logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-node-latest#download-a-blob-and-convert-it-to-a-string-nodejs) .

Through debugging, I notice one interesting point is that I see in my Node_Modules, under `@azure`:

[image: folderStructure]

I noticed when I install it in other places outside my app, it does not create a Node_Modules subfolder and it works fine. Could this setup configuration have anything to do with the issue I am having? I have uninstalled and re-installed a couple times as well. I am unsure but it seems it shouldn't take me to that subFolder.. it should take me to the
@azure/core-tracing that's in the same parent folder as @azure/storage-blob.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Edit: I also tried to see if adding more dependecies would help with:
`npm install --save @opentelemetry/api @opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web @opentelemetry/instrumentation-document-load @opentelemetry/context-zone`... still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took some time to track down, sharing here for those that come across this in the future.

**Packages referenced:**

- @azure/storage-blobs @^12.10.0
- @microsoft/applicationinsights @2.0.0 => @2.3.5

This problem started when we re-installed/updated our npm packages. I isolated out the logic in a sandbox to recreate the issue. When isolated it worked fine. This sandbox already had the packages set up, so I went and compared the node_modules folders, and the working app does NOT include opentelementry/tracing. In /tracing that api.isInstrumentationSuppressed is called but the api object does not have that method attached, so node looks for it with no success.

Turn out that extra cruft folder was being created by the old version of applicationinsights (2.0.0) upon installation. Once we updated to LTS of appInsights(v2.3.5), the problem was gone.. no more unneeded /tracing folder created during install.